# Using ng-template and the src attribute

Tags: angularjs

I am developing an Angular application that will be hosted within another third party applications' "html view". This application does not have a webserver behind the scenes; instead, it just serves the files locally.

This means that we cannot load partials the normal way (some restriction related to xhr loading files directly from the local file system, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29530708/angularjs-access-denied-when-loading-partial-in-ie11) I posted a while ago explaining the problem). I've had to make use of the ng-template directive, e.g.

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="tpl-mytemplate">
<div> Hello, World!</div>
</script>
```

What I want to know is if it is possible to use the `src` attribute so that I do not need to inline all of my partials, resulting in a ridiculously large html page. e.g

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="tpl-mytemplate" src="partials/mytemplate.html">
</script>
```

Comment: Have you tried this? There is no problem mentioned :)

Comment: You can define the templateUrl by configuring the $routeProvider -- You then will not need to add the `<script>` tags in your HTML. -- https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider

Comment: I have tried this,  it doesn't seem to work.  Was wondering if there is something else I needed to do